# loading jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min from jquery site

Tags: jquery-ui, file, tabs

Can anyone know the link for loading jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min from j query site like

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>.
```

what are all the .js files needed for jquery tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use google api to load jquery:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
   google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
   google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you include the tabs script with your custom build. To do this go to http://jqueryui.com/download and tick the 'tabs' checkbox.

This will out put a zip file containing images, css and js files.

Next, attach the custom jQuery UI file, aswell as the jQuery file and the relevant CSS files.

Then visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ and check out the source for that demo (click 'view source'). It'll give you the mark up needed to create the tabs.